# pass increment data from second activity to first activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my first `Activity` a "+" button opens the second activity. On the second activity I want to click a button to add to a counter and pass that increment number to my first activity. Right now I am able to add to the counter from the first activity only.

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button addBtn;
int quantity = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

    addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openAddStarActivity();
        }
    });
}

public void openAddStarActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddStarActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            TextView textView = (TextView)
findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
            textView.setText(data.getStringExtra("textViewText"));
        }
    }
}

public void increment(View view) {
    if (quantity == 100) {
        return;
    }
    quantity = quantity + 1;
    displayQuantity(quantity);
}

private void displayQuantity(int numberOfStars) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + numberOfStars);
}



}


AddStarActivity.java
public class AddStarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int quantity = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_star);        

}

public void increment(View view) {
    if (quantity == 100) {
        return;
    }
    quantity = quantity + 1;
    displayQuantity(quantity);
}

private void displayQuantity(int numberOfStars) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + numberOfStars);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    i.putExtra("textViewText", textView.getText().toString());
    startActivityForResult(i,0);
}
}
```

I added a Textview on the second activity so that I could simply pass that textview data to the textview data field on my first activity

Comment: you are setting the result before adding extras to your intent...put the intent.putExtras line before set result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make quantity public static in MainActivity and increment the same static variable in AddStarActivity. So your function will be

```
public void increment(View view) {
    if (MainActivity.quantity == 100) {
        return;
    }
    MainActivity.quantity++;
    displayQuantity(MainActivity.quantity);
}
```

Comment: This worked very well, however when I went back to my MainActivity the updated value did not show until I pressed the increment button on the MainActivity page and it added one more, of course. I slightly changed my MainActivity code to just show quantity without incrementing and I updated the button to be a refresh type button.

Comment: If you want to show that value on screen then you can update the value in onResume() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing with tow way which is bellow

**Broadcast Receiver**
Register Broadcast in your first activity and fire action from your second activity with data like below example
In your first activity

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("SendCounter")) {
                    counter=intent.getIntExtra("value",0);
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter("value"));
```

In your second activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent("SendCounter");
        intent.putExtra("value",counterValue);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Static Member**
Define one variable in your activity and define as static so you can access that particular member as static.

In your first activity

```
public static int counter;
```

Now in your second activity, you can add value in your first activity variable like bellow

```
ActivityFirst.counter=30 //New value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MainActivity should not be calling `startActivity`, but instead should call `startActivityForResult`, when starting AddStarActivity. Then in AddStarActivity, you would call `setResult` when you are incrementing. And finally, remove `onBackPressed` from AddStarActivity. When the user clicks the back button to go from your AddStarActivity back to MainActivity (meaning the system will `finish` the AddStarActivity), then `MainActivity#onActivityResult` will be invoked.